# Have the materials of Benji's opera program been published?

Tags: mission-impossible, mission-impossible-rogue-nation

In *Mission: Impossible - Rogue Nation*, Benji is handed what looks like a paper opera program as he gets off the subway before the opera.

> But a few scenes later, we see him open it up to reveal that it has a touch screen which he uses to Scan security video of the opera house. The fact that the tablet can flip and bend realistically like paper was impressive.

Have the materials used in the tablet program been documented anywhere?

Note: This question does not ask for a scientific explanation. Instead, this question asks **whether the writers and producers of *Mission: Impossible* have documented their pseudo technology, much like Marvel documents schematics for the Ant-Man suit.**

Comment: Are you asking about the contents of the opera, the code used in the tablet, or the physical makeup of the tablet? Your wording is not clear.

Comment: I feel it was more of an e-ink display... Looked very similar. Apart from that, I don't see any such existing documentation so far.

Comment: Is this note at the end still necessary, now that it is not going the risk of being closed for "scientific explanation" anymore? Especially since there might very well exist a reasonable explanation with real-life technology, as the answers seem to show, even if the makers did *not* publish any additional info themselves.

Answer (score 6):

If this answer turns out to not answer what the question is asking about, I'll remove it.

There are flexible displays now, although I don't know of [m]any consumer products that use them. This is probably due to the fact that I haven't been following the news on this technology in particular (although it does show up on occasion), or that they are probably still in the prototype stage of development.

These images are straight from Wikipedia's [Flexible Display](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_display) page
[image]
[image]
[image]

[Apparently LG is developing flexible TVs](http://www.engadget.com/2014/07/09/lg-roll-up-tvs-flexible-oled/)

> It's been a while since we've seen any new curved or flexible displays
>   following LG's G Flex and Samsung's Galaxy Round smartphones. LG
>   Display is thinking bigger now. It's announced that it's been able to
>   create an 18-inch OLED panel that has enough give and flexibility to
>   roll into a tube that's a mere 3cm across. The prototype currently has
>   a resolution of 1,200 x 810, while it's a new polyamide film on the
>   back of the panel (instead of the typical plastic) which offers the
>   panel substantially more flexibility -- and it's also even thinner.

[image]